# Link theme options page using ACF to styles

Tags: css, advanced-custom-fields, theme-options, sass

Forgive me, I'm very much a beginner.

I'm looking into custom theme development and creating a theme options page. Using the options page, I want to set a primary color that will be used across all buttons, featured sections ect.

To do this, I have created a color picker using acf in theme options.

Can I use this color as a variable in SASS or do I need to call the color in PHP and display the scc internally?